# Comparing strings with numbers

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
console.log("str4" > "str16"); // true
```

I'm getting true from the above statement. I want to sort the same strings with different numbers, something like:

```
str1
str2
...
str9
str10
str11
str12
```

Just like MySQL would do this, but javascript gives me different results. How could I deal with this? I use normal `Array.sort` method.

Comment: use Array#sort with a function callback, and do your own grunt work

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
arr = ["str3", "str4", "str2", "str44"]

arr.sort(function(a,b){  return (a.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.match(/\d+/)[0]) })

// output ["str2", "str3", "str4", "str44"]
```

Comment: of course, that assumes all alpha portions are the same :p